# Create apple notes with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I get the text from the file and create a note, but the text is added to the notes without hyphenation, in one line! How to make all hyphenations be copied?

My code:

```
set x to read POSIX file "/files/mytext.txt"

tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        make new note at folder "Blogs" with properties {name:"My Blogs", body:x}
    end tell
end tell
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered that the "Notes" application is actually using HTML format (it said so in the AppleScript Dictionary for that application), and HTML does not correctly format newlines; so that means that all of the newlines need to be replaced with `<br>` using the shell command `awk`. Reading the file using `awk` instead of AppleScript itself also seems to solve the hyphenation problem.

Here is the fixed command:

```
set x to (do shell script "awk '{printf \"%s\\<br>\", $0}' '/files/mytext.txt'")

tell application "Notes"
    tell account "iCloud"
        make new note at folder "Blogs" with properties {name:"My Blogs", body:x}
    end tell
end tell
```